# Что не так с this?

Tags: javascript, this, конструктор

Никак не могу понять почему в строке присвоения this.id = 120 браузер ругается. Что не так с this?

```
class Proba {
 constructor(){
   this.id;
 }
 anim () {
   function go () {
     this.id = 120;
     console.log(this.id);
   }
   go();
 }
}

let proba = new Proba();
proba.anim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит потому что теряется контекст класса в функции `go`. Необходима привязка! Код ниже. Либо используйте стрелочную функцию (код второй). Прочтите что такое [Привязка контекста к функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind)

```js
class Proba {
 constructor(){
   this.id;
 }
 anim () {
   function go () {
     this.id = 120;
     console.log(this.id);
   }
   go.bind(this)();
 }
}

let proba = new Proba();
proba.anim();
```

```js
class Proba {
 constructor(){
   this.id;
 }
 anim () {
   const go = () => {
     this.id = 120;
     console.log(this.id);
   }
   go();
 }
}

let proba = new Proba();
proba.anim();
```

Comment: ок. большое спс. попробую...